# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined, while passing value for calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me to solve this?
This is my code, and error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" and I currently using jQuery 1.10.2

```
for (var i in shop) {
   var item = shop[i];
   str = parseFloat(item.Price.replace("₹", "").replace(/,/g,''));
   var tol = item.Qty * str;
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: after this line `var item = shop[i];` can you share the output of `console.log(item)`?

Comment: Does `item` has `Price` property?

Comment: You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: item.Price  is nil.check in console

Comment: provide details of your `shop` object with some dummy data so that we can help you

Comment: Item has the ID for corresponding shop and console.log(item) will give ID. @gurvinder372

Comment: @MukundaBhatta you're not answering the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If as you say `Item has the ID for shop and console.log(item) will give ID` - that sounds very much like `item` is just a string, and strings obviously do not have a `Price` property.

So `item.Price` returns `undefined`, and trying to call a method on `undefined` gives the error you are getting.

You need to resolve/convert the string to a real item (e.g. a Product object?), either right here inside this method, or at the place where you construct the `shop` object.